# Published ClickOnce application not appearing in Start menu

Tags: c#, installation, windows-10, clickonce, publish

I have a ClickOnce application that does not appear listed in the Start menu when published (and installed). [According to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699224.aspx), one can enter info in **Publisher name** or **Product name**. I have both filled in, yet I see nothing in the Start menu.

What can I do?

(Windows 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Publish Wizard, one is asked:
*Will the application be available offline?*

Select Yes and a shortcut will be added to Start Menu.

This changes Shell.csproj like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Install>true</Install>
```